# Convert Algebraic Expression directly into Binary Tree Structure (sans prefix / postfix)

Tags: algorithm, binary-tree

I am looking all over internet to find a logic to convert an Algebraic Expression into a Binary Tree.

I could only find ones where you first convert the algebra expression to postfix or prefix and then convert it to Binary Tree.

I did try come with logic , but it didnt work in all cases, the issue was with choosing the correct Operand as the Root Parent node. I coudnt find a generalized logic to crack that.

I am just curious to know , if its possible.

Any pointers to external links or logical answers to put me in the right direction ?

### Edit

yes A Syntax Tree

So this expression

```
A+(B-C)*D+E*F
```

should be translated into

```
              |-(+)-|
              |     |
    |---(*)---|     |---(*)---|
    |         |     |         |
|---(+)---|   D     E         F
|         |
|         |
A   |--( - )--|
    |         |
    B          C
```

Comment: Can you provide an example? What do you mean by _"convert an Algebraic Expression into a Binary Tree"_ Do you mean some kind of syntax-tree related to the Algebraic Expression?

Comment: Just for correctness: This translation is wrong since * has a higher precedence then +. The syntax tree is equivalent to (A+(B-C))*D+E*F

Answer (score -1):

My simple suggestion is to:

- Parse the expression and separate it like this `A`, `+(B-C)*D` and `+E*F`.
- Try to group those groups by number of variables/operations so that you can roughly split the expression in half - for example group `A` and `-(E*F)` in one group - `A - E*F` and the other is `+(B-C)*D`. Now you could split every group recursively into nodes and leaves.

EDIT:

It would result in something like this

step 1:

```
String left = "A - E*F";
String right = "+(B-C)*D";
```

step 2:

```
    |------------(+)---------|
    |                        |
|---(-)---|             |---(*)---|
|         |             |         |
|         |             |         D
A   |--(*)--|      |---(-)---|
    |       |      |         |
    E       F      B         C
```

Of course, all this means that your [parser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parser) should be aware of the [Order of operations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_precedence)